# SOQL query all tasks and events with opportunities and any connected campaigns

Tags: soql, opportunity, query, activities, campaign

I'm fairly new to SOQL but I need to write a query that returns all activities (Events and Tasks) that are associated with an opportunity. In addition I'd like to get any campaigns that are influencing the opportunity.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any relation between opportunity and Campaign like lookup?

Comment: @salesforce learner, Not sure if I understand completely but essentially any campaign that has influenced the opportunity that the activity is associated with.

Comment: SELECT Id, Name,Campaign.Name,Campaign.NumberOfOpportunities,(SELECT Id FROM Tasks), (SELECT Id FROM Events) FROM opportunity WHERE Name = 'Test opp'

Comment: ERROR: 'No such relation 'Campaign' on entity 'Opportunity''

Comment: Can you post the exact query which you tried?

Comment: SELECT Id, Name,Campaign.Name,Campaign.NumberOfOpportunities,(SELECT Id FROM Tasks), (SELECT Id FROM Events) FROM opportunity WHERE Name = 'Cardinal'

Comment: try this:   Opportunity opp=[SELECT Id, Name,Campaign.Name,(SELECT Id FROM Tasks), (SELECT Id FROM Events) FROM opportunity WHERE Name ='Cardinal'];                System.debug('Opportunity'+opp);

Answer (score 1):

```
Select CampaignId, campaign.name, (Select Id From Tasks), (Select Id  From Events) From Opportunity  WHERE id =: oppid
```

You could quite easily get the SOQL from salesforce schema within eclipse.

Comment: You missed a part of request where OP wants to return the Campaign which influenced the Opportunity as well.

Comment: Mybad, Updated!